# Flutter : Timer.periodic running multiple times in each iteration

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile-development

I am trying to make snake 2 in flutter. And I have used Timer.periodic() for game loop. And I tried specifying duration as 1 seconds. But the code inside the Timer.periodic() runs multiple times in a second. I also tried debugging (though I am terrible at that) and found that the code inside the Timer.periodic() ran multiple times without stepping out of it. Though while debugging this couild happen as the code pauses for input. But I'm not sure about anything .Here is my code -

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SnakePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SnakePageState createState() => _SnakePageState();
}

class _SnakePageState extends State<SnakePage> {
  int score = 0;
  String swipe = '';
  bool running = false;
  int iterates = 0;
  List snake = [
    [
      [4, 3],
      1,
      true
    ],
    [
      [4, 2],
      1,
      false
    ],
    [
      [4, 1],
      1,
      false
    ],
  ];

  // Convert radians to degree
  double radians(double degree) {
    return ((degree * 180) / pi);
  }

  void turn(moveEvent) {
       double angle = radians(moveEvent.delta.direction);
      if (angle >= -45 && angle <= 45) {
        this.swipe = 'Swipe Right';
      } else if (angle >= 45 && angle <= 135) {
        this.swipe = 'Swipe Down';
      } else if (angle <= -45 && angle >= -135) {
        this.swipe = 'Swipe Up';
      } else {
        this.swipe = 'Swipe Left';
      }
  }

  int toIndex(coOrdinates) {
    return ((coOrdinates[0] + 1) * 10) + coOrdinates[1];
  }

  void run() {
    this.running = true;
    Timer.periodic(
        Duration(
          milliseconds: 500,
        ), (timer) {
      this.setState(() {
        this.iterates += 1;
        this.swipe = this.iterates.toString();
        for (var i = 0; i < this.snake.length; i++) {
          this.snake[i][0][1] += 1;
          if (this.snake[i][0][1] == 10) {
            this.snake[i][0][1] = 0;
          }
        }
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('WC'),
      ),
      body: Listener(
            onPointerMove: this.running
                ? (moveEvent) => this.turn(moveEvent)
                : (moveEvent) => this.run(),// Where the function is being called
            child: Container();
    );
  }
}
```

And please pardon me for code being a mess and not well commented.
Any Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that, every time you execute the `run()` method, a new timer is created and you listen for it, again. The old timer is not stopped, so it keeps firing.
The solution is, before you create a timer, cancel the previous one. Something like this:

```
class _SnakePageState extends State<SnakePage> {
   Timer? _myTimer;

void run() {
    this.running = true;
    _myTimer?.cancel(); //in case we have a timer, we'll cancel it.
    _myTimer = Timer.periodic(. // assing new timer to our variable.
        Duration(
          milliseconds: 500,
        ), (timer) {
      this.setState(() {
        this.iterates += 1;
        this.swipe = this.iterates.toString();
        for (var i = 0; i < this.snake.length; i++) {
          this.snake[i][0][1] += 1;
          if (this.snake[i][0][1] == 10) {
            this.snake[i][0][1] = 0;
          }
        }
      });
    });
  }

 
}
```

Comment: But I have created a variable running and it is set true once the function is called and after that it calls turns function that has nothing to do with Timer.periodic(), though your given solution works for me, but I can't understand how the run function is called multiple times.

Comment: @PriyanshuJangra Your ```running``` variable doesn't stop the execution of the timer block, if the timer is not canceled.

Answer (score 0):

While using the timer periodic function in Flutter, It may run multiple times when re-entering to page, cuz the previous instance is not closed. Add the below code in dispose or where you are cancelling your timer function. Because it never comes out of the loop until and unless it cancels your timer function. Once your timer gets canceled your timer will not run in multiple times.

```
    do {
      timer.cancel();
    } while (timer.isActive);
    do {
      timer2.cancel();
    } while (timer2.isActive);
```

posting answers may be late but it may help others too.

**IF YOU REALLY DON'T WANT TO USE PERIODIC**

The best solution to get your data in a realtime is WebSockets, You can use WebSockets for real-time data updates from DB to client.